# How can i install xfonts-... packages?

Tags: command-line, apt, xorg, 14.10

I need to install `xfonts-100dpi` `xfonts-75dpi` `xfonts-scalable` `xfonts-cyrillic` packages.
But I get an error, that they are not exists. Using Ubuntu 14.10

Need them for xvfb

Comment: The error message and how did you install it will be essential to this kind of questions, please update your question, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First enable the Ubuntu Partner Software

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then update your software list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can get a list of installable fonts by searching for packages beginning with fonts- and xfonts-.

```
apt-cache search fonts | grep '^xfonts-'
```

Now you can install what you want

```
sudo apt-get install -y xfonts-...
```

Comment: if someone will need, commands to install fonts:
`sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic`