# How to install xfonts on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, fonts

I installed **xfonts-100dpi** on Ubuntu 20.04 using

`apt install xfonts-100dpi`

They show up in **/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi**. All the files are in a ***.pcf.gz** format.

When I run `fc-list` they are not listed. If I run `fc-cache -fv | grep 100dpi` I get the following,

```
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi: caching, new cache contents: 358 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi: skipping, looped directory detected
```

`fc-list` still does not list them after the forced cache update, neither does the `font-manager` app.

What am I doing wrong here?

NOTE: the following did not help: [How can i install xfonts-... packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613190/how-can-i-install-xfonts-packages)

Comment: Being gzipped sounds odd. You may want to try this command: `sudo gunzip /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/*`

Comment: @Gunnar. I thought the same thing. I did unzip them all and reran `fc-cache -fv | grep 100dpi` but got the same `skipping, looped directory detected` message...

Comment: can confirm this.

Comment: did you found the solution.